# How to use Excel VBA replace function with case sensitivity?

Tags: vba, excel, replace, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

This code should replace the words with the case typed by the user, instead it always replaces with the first searc ignoring the case.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
Sub chaser()

Range(Range("B15"), Range("B15").End(xlDown)).Replace what:="Part of chair", replacement:="Chair part"
Range(Range("B15"), Range("B15").End(xlDown)).Replace what:="part of chair", replacement:="chair part"

End Sub
```

Result:

```
Chair part
Chair part
```

should be:

```
Chair part
chair part
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Add the `MatchCase:=True` See [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx) for all the options.

Comment: Nice, looks like what im looking for. Could u show me where should I write it?

Comment: Put `, MatchCase:=True` at the end of each of the two lines.

Comment: Worked perfectly !The new code is:

Range(Range("B15"), Range("B15").End(xlDown)).Replace what:="Part of chair", replacement:="Chair part", MatchCase:=True

Comment: Could you please make it an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the MatchCase criteria; `MatchCase:=True`.

Just add it to the end of your existing statements:

```
Sub chaser()

Range(Range("B15"), Range("B15").End(xlDown)).Replace what:="Part of chair", replacement:="Chair part", MatchCase:=True
Range(Range("B15"), Range("B15").End(xlDown)).Replace what:="part of chair", replacement:="chair part", MatchCase:=True

End Sub
```

See [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx) for more information on Range.Replace.